# Will there be a conflict between my Sitemap.xml and robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, web-crawlers, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have a *robots.txt* with the following in it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: http://tests.compkerworld.com/report_question_error.php?question_id=*&url=*
Sitemap: http://tests.compkerworld.com/sitemap.xml
```

My *sitemap.xml*, which is auto-generated, has all the URLs even those disallowed using *robots.txt*.

I have no problem if the search engines crawl all the pages, but I want to know if such an entry will create any kind of conflict for crawlers.

One more question: is the above syntax for disallowing correct?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) in regards to your syntax (you don't need the protocol and root, if placed in the root directory).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [Google will *not* crawl them and will report them as being blocked in Google Webmasters Tools](http://www.webmasterworld.com/robots_txt/4621798.htm). If that error message, which does not affect your rankings, is annoying to you then you will need to remove those pages from your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The question came into my mind because the number of disallowed pages are 5 times the allowed pages and the disallowed pages are there in sitemap.xml. Just curious to know if it's a good practice or I should think of a way to get clean sitemap.xml.

Comment: If you can find a way to clean up your sitemap that would be good as it prevents your GWT from being cluttered up with unnecessary error messages.